# Ensure a full array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array and I set to this array random values. I want to be to be sure that this array is full (there is a number in each position).How can I ensure about this? I wrote the following code but I’m not sure.

```
 public boolean check(){
  boolean checks=false;        
  int [] array =new int [10];

  if(array.length==10){
     checks = true;     
  }

 return checks;
}
```

Comment: is zero a valid generated random number?

Comment: An array in Java is always "full". The entries you haven't explicitly filled in contain the default value (0 or null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays always have a value at each position, though those values might not be values that you've set.  The code you have above will always set `check` to `true` (assuming, of course, that you don't get a memory exception when you allocate the array), since if you ask for an array of length 10 that's precisely what you're going to get.  You might want to change those values later by doing some sort of `for` loop over them generating random values, but if you ask for space for 10 elements you don't have to worry that your array will have some sort of "hole" in it where there isn't any space.

Similarly, there's no way to check whether you've ever assigned to some array location or whether it's still holding the default value.  You will have to manage this yourself.  That said, if you do a for loop like this one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = /* ... */
}
```

You can guarantee that every element  of the array has had a value assigned to it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can't, if you're randomly generating among all possible ints (note that currently you're not doing any such random generation).  The default element value (0), is obviously one of those ints.  Note that the `length` is fixed, and has nothing to do with what elements you've initialized.

You could use an array of Integers, but that's unnecessary overhead.  Just keep track with a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

you can use an `Integer` array, and then check if there are any nulls:

```
public boolean check(){
  boolean checks=false;        
  Integer [] array =new Integer [10];

  // generate random numbers

  // check if there are any empty spots.
  for(Integer i : array) {
    if(i == null) return false;
  }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "there is a number in each position"?

Java doesn't allow sparse arrays (arrays with gaps in them) - do you mean "all numbers are not zero"? If so, the following code may work for you:

```
public boolean check(int [] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) { 
        if(array[i] == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check an array doesn't contain `null` elements, you can use something like this:

```
int [] array = new int[7];

//Step 1
boolean b = false;

//Step 2
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] == null){
        b = true;
    }
}

//Step 3
if(!b){
    System.out.println("Array is full");
}
```

> Step 1

As a start create boolean variable called `b` to hold your result and set its value to `false`.

> Step 2

Loop through the array you want to check and look for a `null` elements in which case you set `b` to `true`

> Step 3

Finally just check the value for `b` and do whatever you want with the result. In my example if the array doesn't contain `null` elements it will print "Array is full"